# Golden ratio approximation function with a number bound between successor and predecessor to break

Tags: python

```
def approximation_of_golden_ratio(eps):
    first_k = 1
    while True:
        next_k = 1 + 1/first_k
        if eps > (next_k - first_k):
            break
        first_k = next_k
    return next_k
```

This function should return the first golden ratio approximation, that is less than `eps` away from it's predecessor.
The formula is: golden_ratio_approximation = 1 + 1/predecessor , to get the next number approximation.

```
approximation_of_golden_ratio(0.1)
```

returns 1.5 instead of 1.6.

I don't see what is wrong with my code.

Comment: `next_k - first_k` is not the difference between your current value and the real one, it's the difference between two successive estimates. In general, there's no reason why this difference being smaller than `eps` implies that you are less than `eps` away from the exact value.

Comment: I have found what is wrong yes, it should be absolute value. I also answered my own question for anybody that might need a solution to a similar problem. I am not familiar how accepted it is to accept your own answers on this forum. I can also delete the whole question if you think that is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found, what is wrong. I should have used absolute value to get distance and not normal subtraction.

> if eps > abs(next_k - first_k):

```
def approximation_of_golden_ratio(eps):
first_k = 1
while True:
    next_k = 1 + 1/first_k
    if eps > abs(next_k - first_k):
        break
    first_k = next_k
return next_k
```

Comment: This is the appropriate approach because the order of the terms shouldn't matter (`abs(next_k - first_k)` must be equal to `abs(first_k - next_k)`), because what you want is the difference and not the result of a subtraction